# Memory position of elements in C/C++ union

Tags: c++, c, c++11, unions, c11

I have a union in C like this:

```
union AUnion {
  struct CharBuf {
    char *buf;
    size_t len;
  } charbuf;
  uint8_t num;
  double fp_num;
};
```

My question is, can I guarantee that if given the following:

```
union AUnion u;
```

Then the following are true:

```
&u == &u.num
&u == &u.fp_num
&u == &u.charbuf
```

I.e they all start at the beginning of the memory segment where `u` is stored.

In the case of this C program compiled with `gcc version 5.3.0` and `-std=c11` the above is true:

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdint.h>
#include <stdlib.h>

union AUnion {
    struct CharBuf {
        char *buf;
        size_t len;
    } charbuf;
    uint8_t num;
    double fp_num;
};

int main(void)
{
    union AUnion u;
    printf("%d\n", ((void*)&u) == ((void*)&u.charbuf));
    printf("%d\n", ((void*)&u.charbuf) == ((void*)&u.num));
    printf("%d\n", ((void*)&u.num) == ((void*)&u.fp_num));
}
```

As it prints:

```
1
1
1
```

Compiling the code above as C++11 with the same compiler results in the same output as compiling it as C11.

But is this standardized behaviour? Is it undefined? Can I rely on this behaviour with most C compilers? Can I expect this behaviour with C++ compilers as well?

Comment: C++ doesn't treat union any differently than c

Comment: @UriBrecher actually there are many differences

Comment: @M.M: Then tell that how `union` differs in C & C++ ? List out the many differences If you think so !!!

Comment: @Destructor too much to fit in comments. Post a question if you are curious (or find an existing one)

Comment: I guess you're right, there are some features that C++ adds to unions which are not supported in C. However, both languages exhibit the same behaviour in regards to aligning all members to the same position in memory.

Comment: Is there no good duplicate for this? I feel like this is a FAQ.

Answer (score 14, accepted):

In [6.7.2.1p16](http://port70.net/~nsz/c/c11/n1570.html#6.7.2.1p16) the C standard guarantees that:

> The size of a union is sufficient to contain the largest of its members. The value of at most one of the members can be stored in a union object at any time. **A pointer to a union object, suitably converted, points to each of its members** (or if a member is a bit- field, then to the unit in which it resides), and vice versa.

So, yes, you can rely on all members starting at the `union`s address (note this is the same for the first member of a `struct`).

The C++ standard includes a similar sentence with respect to C-style (i.e. only C-style members) `union`s/`struct`s, because C++ allows to pass `union`s to C functions which does require this layout.The relevant section in the C++ standard is 9.5.

---

**However**, note there might be padding *bits* inside standard simple types (integers, floats). And their internal may vary (endianess). You also might violate *strict aliasing rule* (C: *effective type*).

Comment: This makes an assumption that pointer conversions can never change the memory address. This is untrue in C++. For example, multiple inheritance is one way to witness it. The fact that "suitably converted" has occurred does not prove _anything_ about where the members are in memory.

Comment: @AsteroidsWithWings Can you please cite the paragraph in the C++ standard? I'm not that familiar with C++ like I am with C, so I didn't expect ´union´s can be inherited at all. Plase note this is not about other types and only C-style members, which excludes inherited (wasn't I clear enough in my answer?).

Answer (score 9):

From my experience, I would say 'yes', though I've checked the [C++14 standard](http://www.open-std.org/jtc1/sc22/wg21/docs/papers/2013/n3797.pdf) and it even guarantees this. (c++11 will most likely have the same effects) Chapter 9.5 states: `All non-static data members of a union object have the same address`

So, you can depend on this behavior.

Comment: That says nothing about the address of the union itself.